# add_filter the_content str_replace after shortcode

Tags: php, html, forms, autocomplete

I want to add a PHP `str_replace` to the `add_filter('the_content')` function. I believe my problem is that the shortcodes are loading after the `str_replace` is called.

I have a shortcode that outputs a form, i want to make it that in all HTML form tags, the attribute `autocomplete='off'`.

Heres the code i have.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'disable_autocomplete');
function disable_autocomplete( $content )
{
    return str_replace('<form', '<form autocomplete="off"', $content);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the priority of actions and filters, it's the third argument of `add_filter` (and `add_action`) and it defaults to 10.  So change it to a high number and have your filter fire way after the shortcodes and other stuff are inserted.

```
<?php 
add_filter('the_content', 'disable_autocomplete', 99);
function disable_autocomplete( $content )
{
    return str_replace('<form', '<form autocomplete="off"', $content);
}
```

Comment: Ahh! So annoying! I put 30 there and it didn't help. Next time ill go higher ;) thanks!